# Hide URL pathname and hash for index page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, user-interface

I have 2 pages Home and Services. In page one(Home) with smooth scrolling moving to ABOUT,CONTACT,WHYUS from navbar using id's. From second page(Services) if clicked on ABOUT or CONTACT of page one(home) using id's it is showing exact position but getting URL like `https://www.example.com/index#about`, `https://www.example.com/index#contact`

The code for Page one (Home) is below.

```html
    <nav>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a class="smooth_scroll" href="#slider">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a class="smooth_scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="service.html">SERVICES</a></li>
          <li><a class="smooth_scroll" href="#whyus">WHY US</a></li>
          <li><a class="smooth_scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

The code for Page two (Services) is below.

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <nav>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
       <li><a href="index.html#about">ABOUT</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="/service.html">SERVICES</a></li>
       <li><a href="index.html#pricing">WHY US</a></li>
       <li><a href="index.html#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

How do I get the URL like `https://www.example.com` instead of `https://www.example.com/index#about`, or `https://www.example.com/index#contact` when navigating from Page two (services) to Page one(Home), I don't want the `index#id` to be displayed in the URL.

So, Please suggest how to remove it using Javascript/Jquery/Html/Css etc.

Answer (score 0):

try to the full link and rename index.html on index.php

https://www.example.com/(index.php if it's index page, you can not write index.php )#about

href="https://www.example.com/#about"

Comment: it is completely html project. not using php

Comment: If you're using IIS (or any other non-php server) then you don't want to rename an html file php

Answer (score 0):

You can replace links to `index.html` by `/` (root) on most servers, and it will work just fine.

```html
<li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
```

To remove `#hash`, you can use an event listener to detect it changes.

```js
function removeHash() {
  // Option 1: This will only remove the part after "#", i.e. hash value
  window.location.hash = "";

  // Option 2: This will split the URL by "#" and use the part before it
  history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href.split("#")[0]);
}

// Remove hash whenever hash is changed
window.addEventListener('hashchange', removeHash, false);

// Run it once when page loads
removeHash();
```

NOTE: Don't use both options above! Otherwise it will become a infinite recursion.

Comment: Where should I call this removeHash() function? 
can you please guide me, very new to html thing.

Comment: @Bharath In the script attached to the `index.html` file.

Comment: I added internally script file, it is not working.

Comment: @Bharath You have to give more details than "it is not working". What is not working exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I added your code exactly in a script tag of index.html (which is main file) but it did not remove the #id from the URL.

Comment: @Bharath I have tested this myself to be working. Don't add exact code snippet above, add as you need. Use only one of the options in the function `removeHash()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234969/discussion-between-bharath-and-amith).